# Running code in background after creating window

Tags: python, user-interface

I wanted to create a basic GUI for existing Python code, however most frameworks that allow creation of user interface require some kind of window loop. I wanted to create a window with a button that "listens" for the buttonpress while running code.

Using pseudocode:

```
CreateWindowWithButton(window, button1, button1.text = "False")
arg = False
while(True):
    do_something(arg)
    if window.button1.isPressed():
        arg = not arg
        window.button1.text = str(arg)
    if keypressed("Escape"):
        break
DestroyWindow(window)
```

Comment: Your code has a loop.

Comment: they require a loop for a reason.. you can either try a really easy graphic lib like pygame (lots of examples and tutorials) or dig into [python threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or both

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Nov 2022
I see from a comment that one of my old SO posts has done with these sometimes do.... age poorly.

Some problems with SO include:

- You get the most popular answer, which may not be the best answer
- Software evolves, the answers on SO do not.

The original code in this answer was posted 2 months after the initial release of PySimpleGUI, over 4 years ago. It no longer runs and it uses patterns that are not recommended now. The `window.ReadNonBlocking` doesn't exist anymore.

**The best place to ask questions is on a project's GitHub.**

This is a "corrected" version of the code originally posted.  It too may age poorly:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Click the button to trigger main loop')],
          [sg.Button('Escape')]]

window = sg.Window('My new window', layout)

while True:                                         # Event Loop
    # do_something()                                # Do whatever you want
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)        # Reads without blocking the program (like polling) every 100 ms
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Escape': # If X button was clicked, or the button
        break
window.close()
```

---

Since you've not specified a GUI framework, I suggest trying [PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org), a tkinter wrapper.

This code creates a window with a button and then reads the button in a while loop just as in your example pseudo-code.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Click the button to trigger main loop')],
          [sg.RButton('My Button')]]

window = sg.Window('My new window').Layout(layout)

while True:                                         # Event Loop
    # do_something()                                # Do whatever you want
    button, value = window.ReadNonBlocking()        # Reads without blocking the program (like polling)
    if value is None:                               # If X button was clicked
        break
    elif button == 'My Button':                       # If got the button click we want
        print('Received the button press')
        break
```

The code produces this window:

[image]

Comment: comment in PySimpleGui says:

```Should be NEVER called directly by the user.  The user can call Window.Read(timeout=0) to get same effect```